# Android Studio - Error when using implementation

Tags: android-studio

When I try to add this line:

```
implementation ‘petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.10’
```

I got the error:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\Ronald beltan\AndroidStudioProjects\SimplyDrawV2

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

8: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5s
20 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 12 up-to-date
```

Can anyone help me? Any additional questions will be entertained, Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this library was located at JCenter repository, so check your project `build.gradle` file and add `jcenter()`

**Attention :** JCenter Maven repository is no longer receiving updates:

Comment: Thank you! I was literally searching this for days and could not find the solution. Newer versions didn't had this line by default so maybe because it's not getting updates anymore, but still, Thank you again! You saved my project